# Why getting selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException in selenium python Script?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium and written a script to login, and when I am running the script getting the following error:-

**Error:-**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="SignIn Form_email"]"}
```

**Script:-**

```
url = "https://someurl.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\CustomDrivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
user_id = driver.find_element_by_id("SignIn Form_email")
user_id.send_keys("admin@web.com")

user_password = driver.find_element_by_id("SignIn Form_password")
user_password.send_keys("web$$DD")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='SignIn Form']/div[3]/div/div/div/button").click()
print(driver.title)
time.sleep(5)
```

**Full Error Trace:-**

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\logintest.py:6: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\CustomDrivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver")
Convin
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\logintest.py:9: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  user_id = driver.find_element_by_id("SignIn Form_email")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\logintest.py", line 9, in <module>
    user_id = driver.find_element_by_id("SignIn Form_email")
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 466, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1238, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="SignIn Form_email"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00780C43+2493507]
    Ordinal0 [0x0071A4B1+2073777]
    Ordinal0 [0x00622608+1058312]
    Ordinal0 [0x0064CAA4+1231524]
    Ordinal0 [0x00676C62+1404002]
    Ordinal0 [0x0066597A+1333626]
    Ordinal0 [0x00675038+1396792]
    Ordinal0 [0x0066580B+1333259]
    Ordinal0 [0x00642314+1188628]
    Ordinal0 [0x0064316F+1192303]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00907BF6+1548950]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009B461C+2256060]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0080C13B+518107]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0080B1E0+514176]
    Ordinal0 [0x0071F53D+2094397]
    Ordinal0 [0x00723418+2110488]
    Ordinal0 [0x00723552+2110802]
    Ordinal0 [0x0072CE81+2150017]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7602FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77467A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77467A6E+238]
```

Thanks in advance
Hope to  here from you soon.

Comment: Html element of the sign in form email?

Comment: without url for this page it is waste of time

Answer (score 2):

Where is the HTML? Without it, we can't really help you.

By the way, your `user_id` and `user_password` look like a class name, are you sure about `find_element_by_id` method?
Shouldn't you use `find_element_by_class` instead?

Answer (score 0):

By seeing this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="SignIn Form_email"]"}
```

You will have to make sure

1. This `[id="SignIn Form_email"]` is not under an `iframe`.
2. This `[id="SignIn Form_email"]` is not under a `shadow-root`.
3. You should not be on the new tab/windows launched by selenium.
4. You may be trying to interact with the element and it has not rendedered completely.

Also,
Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
[id="SignIn Form_email"]
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Now, if it is `iframe`, please switch to `iframe first`.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "")))
```

if it is `element` not rendered issue, Please induce web driver wait like

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```