# Why does error 'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector": ""' even it exist?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Python and Selenium. I have written code in which a line is resulting in the error *Message: no such element: Unable to locate element*, even though it exist.

**Code Segment:**

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='react-joyride-step-0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button").click()
```

**Full error log:**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57704/devtools/browser/2ecf6fa2-0489-46a9-b304-95cc40b4c2cc
Convin
logged in
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\logintest.py", line 38, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='react-joyride-step-0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button").click()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1238, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='react-joyride-step-0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div
/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00780C43+2493507]
        Ordinal0 [0x0071A4B1+2073777]
        Ordinal0 [0x00622608+1058312]
        Ordinal0 [0x0064CAA4+1231524]
        Ordinal0 [0x00676C62+1404002]
        Ordinal0 [0x0066597A+1333626]
        Ordinal0 [0x00675038+1396792]
        Ordinal0 [0x0066580B+1333259]
        Ordinal0 [0x00642314+1188628]
        Ordinal0 [0x0064316F+1192303]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00907BF6+1548950]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009B461C+2256060]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0080C13B+518107]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0080B1E0+514176]
        Ordinal0 [0x0071F53D+2094397]
        Ordinal0 [0x00723418+2110488]
        Ordinal0 [0x00723552+2110802]
        Ordinal0 [0x0072CE81+2150017]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7602FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77467A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77467A6E+238]

PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C4800:29492:1123/114516.398:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability s
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C ends.
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^Cn_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^Cmpl.cc(214)] [11:45:16.398] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to th
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^Cn_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that th
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^Cmpl.cc(214)] [11:45:16.400] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to th
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^Cn_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\convin\automation_test> ^C0360:29660:1123/114708.812:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

**Developer console screenshot:**

[image: Developer console screenshot]

Comment: Can you share page url ?

Comment: Also, I see this question have already been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70062003/why-getting-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-in-selenium-python/70069657#70069657

Comment: @cruisepandey my bad luck I can't

Comment: Check if it is in any iframe or not. does not look to be. But it's better to cross verify.

Comment: @cruisepandey how to check it

Comment: Just scroll up little bit in HTML, and see if there's an iframe

Comment: @cruisepandey I have added an answer please have a look!

Comment: I have explained why.. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Skip**, you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Skip'][aria-label='Skip'][data-action='skip']").click()
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Skip' and @aria-label='Skip'][@data-action='skip']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on a ***clickable*** element, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613), and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Skip'][aria-label='Skip'][data-action='skip']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Skip' and @aria-label='Skip'][@data-action='skip']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
skip = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='react-joyride-step-0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", skip)
```

Comment: This could because your web application uses Ajax/JS synchronously and hence need to executed JS code through execute_script

execute_script method synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame. This is a big feature of selenium because javascript can do everything with a website from hitting APIs to playing with live code.